# How can I add the image in component for fullscreen in angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a home component which is the main page of my application and I tried to show some images on full screen with no scrolling.
Is this the correct way of doing it? please check my code and advise.

My goal is to set some image on fullscreen.

**HomeComponent**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  page = {
    title: 'Home',
    subtitle: 'Welcome Home!',
    content: 'Some home content.',
    image: 'assets/images/home.jpeg'
  };
}
```

**HomePage HTML**

```
<img class="fullBg" [src]="page.image">
```

Comment: Hello, its me. If it works - it's correct))) One thing that I should to add it's `alt` attribute to the tag `<img>`. Probably in the css you have something like `.fullBg {height: 100vh; width: 100vw;}`. IMHO, that's ok. =)

Comment: @alexJS no dude it's not working as expected

Comment: so, could you clarify the question? Can you describe what exactly doesn't work as you expect? Maybe upload some screenshot, etc. Let's fix that s$#t.